# Alogrithm to analyze series

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

Is there an algorithm that can find the recurrence relation causing a given serie?

For example:

Serie: 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127

Enter this serie in an algorithm and it finds out the "most parsimonious" (or one of the most parsimonious) recurrence relation. In my example, the equation is

`x(t+1) = x(t)*2 + 1`

Comment: "most parsimonious" - the smallest number of parameters, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: WolframAlpha does this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+3%2C+7%2C+15%2C+31%2C+63%2C+127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. In common case this problem upcomes to [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) problem, which is [incomputable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Incomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity) in terms of algorithm theory.

May be, if you'll add conditions for your function (for example, it is polynom with discrete coefficients and powers) - then you'll have a chance.

Comment: I don't think continuous coefficients will change the problem much (if anything, it will make it easier) (solving something like `x(t+1) = x(t)*c + d` should be pretty straight-forward for continuous values of `c` and `d`). The only problem is with continuous powers.

Comment: Yes, may be. It's hard to predict that - but I think, that's not the stuff which topic starter needs. So it's just can not be resolved.